# Xcode iOS SDK compatibility

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

How does the statement "The project should be compatible with iOS 4.0 and must run on iOS 4.3", effect the coding and judgment of Xcode version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should be compatible with IOS 4.0

This means that you need to set your deployment target to 4.0 or lower.  If you use any post-4.0 frameworks, they must be weak-linked, you cannot rely on them, and you must test for them before using them.  Same goes for post-4.0 classes and selectors - you can't rely on them and you must test for them before using them.  Simplest solution is simply to not use anything that isn't in 4.0.

> must run on IOS 4.3

In general, everything that works on 4.0 will work on 4.3, so there's not much to worry about here.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode version doesn't really matter.  What matters is the version of the iOS SDK.

You can really use any version of the iOS SDK. Anything developed with any version of the SDK should be compatible with both 4.0 and 4.3.

If you need to use specific features of iOS 4.0 that are not available with previous versions, then you need to use 4.0 or later of the SDK.

In general, you should always use the latest version of the SDK, but set your target's properties to whatever the earliest version of the iOS is supported by your app.

Answer (score 0):

It affects the earliest version of the OS (4.0) against you must test on an actual device.